# PHP script for SQL querying

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm still learning php so please take it easy on me. This might sound a silly question for you guys.

Right so. I have categories lets say Blogs, eCommerce, Portfolios etc. Files according too. Blog.php etc.

I also have functions.php where all my functions are.

MYSQL database is where I store information from them files. Website information, descriptions etc.

I want to have 1 function that queries data from a website just about 1 category so then  I can display it in Blogs.php, eCommerce.php etc. 
My function to query data from mysql looks like this.

This is an example:

```
function querying_category($category){
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $all = $db->query('SELECT * FROM website WHERE category = {$category} ORDER BY id DESC');

    if($all->count()){
       foreach($all->results() as $website){
              $web_data[] = $website;
       }
    }
    return $web_data;
}
```

and then let's say in my blog.php would go like:

```
$category = 'blog';
$website = querying_category($category);
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I want to declare a variable in my blog.php or ecommerce.php etc without rewriting the following query:

```
'SELECT * FROM website WHERE category = {$category} ORDER BY id DESC
```

Can I achieve it with passing in `$category` as an argument in `querying_category()` but declaring `$category` in my blog.php or ecommerce.php?

Comment: Sidenote: Shouldn't that be `return $website;`? I stand at being wrong ;-)

Comment: Yes sorry. I was writting really quick made a mistake :)

Comment: Are you receiving an error? If I had to guess you need to wrap {$category} in single quotes in your query but without an error message i'm not sure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- answer the question. :) Your edit worked

Comment: About `return $website;`? @webAwwards

Comment: About you editing my post.

Comment: You had a few missing indents, the codes were already there; I didn't "add" any code, per se. @webAwwards I noticed them when I was modifying a few things.

Comment: Yeah but the way you did it worked for me. I might have made few mistakes in it. You changed 1 or 2 things which worked wonders. :)

Comment: I honestly don't know what it could be LOL! I merely indented these two lines `$category = 'blog'; $website = querying_category($category);` @webAwwards and added an apostrophe plus highlighted a few function names. Is that what it was?

Comment: If you tell me exactly what it was that triggered it, it might jog my memory. @webAwwards

Comment: I managed to figure it out what was wrong after you edited. I know its not really answering the question but after looking at your edit it started making sense to me whats wrong. Without the edit I'd probably still be thinking

Comment: So basically changing `return $web_data;` to `return $website;` and the two indented lines for `$category = 'blog'; $website = querying_category($category);` @webAwwards Correct?

Comment: It just started to make sense to me. Maybe your own wording of editing  made sense... Anyway I want to give you this... :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: The deed has been done, cheers @webAwwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the editing I made to the question fixed the OP's problem.

There were a few lines of code that were not properly indented along with a few spelling mistakes.

As per the OP's request, this answer has been given in order to close the question.

*However*, this line `return $web_data;` should have been `return $website;`